Understanding three legged Oauth with Ory Hydra
I have been trying to understand three-legged Oauth (auth code flow) with Ory Hydra. I followed this Medium article to do that. I think I followed the article quite well except for one last thing. This is my understanding so far.

The third-party application presents the resource owner with a
link, clicking which takes the application to Hydra authentication
endpoint, which in turn redirects the resource owner to the
authentication endpoint.

Resource owner completes log-in and then gets redirected to the
consent page.

The resource owner completes consent and then gets redirected to the
third-party application with an auth code.

The third party then exchanges the auth code with an access token
from Hydra.


What I am not clear about is what happens next. I don't know how the resource server maps the access token to a user.
Later, when the third-party application presents the token issued by Hydra to the resource server, how does it know which resource owner's information is being requested? In the above process, at no point would the resource server or the log-in server could save the access token mapping it to the resource owner.
How is this done?
Any help is appreciated!
